# Separating linq sub-queries into functions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Forgive me if this has been asked before, but I am unsure exactly what I am asking would be called, which makes searching for it difficult.

I currently have the following LINQ query (using linq to entities):

```
results = (from r in query
       select new PatientReport
       {
           Report = r,
           Patient = (from patient in database.PatientSet
                     where patient.IsActive && patient.Account == r.Account
                     select patient).FirstOrDefault()
       }).ToList();
```

Now this works nicely, linq-to-entities produces a single join query from it, and all is dandy. However, I noticed in a few other parts of my code, I have the following:

```
(from patient in database.PatientSet 
where patient.IsActive && patient.Account == r.Account
select patient).FirstOrDefault()
```

Now, my question is:
Is it possible to have code that would behave the same as the first snippet, but would look like this:

```
results = (from r in query
       select new PatientReport
       {
           Report = r,
           Patient = database.GetActivePatient(r.Account)
       }).ToList();
```

and in the Database class (or perhaps in Patient, or perhaps as  an extension method), there is a function that would assemble the following query (obviously not execute it, as then it could not be run as a part of other queries):

```
public xx GetActivePatient(string account)
{
    return (from patient in database.PatientSet
            where patient.IsActive && patient.Account == r.Account
            select patient).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

Although I understand that the signature of the GetActivePatient would probably be wildly hairy and full of IQueryable or IExpression etc.

Effectively I am trying to create a function that creates a query which can be used as a part of other queries.

Any help (even if it is a 'no, this is not possible') is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use extension function as below:

```
 private Func<DataClasses, String> FunctionName(string account)
 {
      return (from patient in database.PatientSet
        where patient.IsActive && patient.Account == r.Account
        select patient).FirstOrDefault()
 }
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand - wouldn't I for starters need to pass the data context across (or the IQueryable dataset)?

Answer (score -1):

An example of a ToString() type extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ToString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    return list.Select(t => t.ToString());
}
```

This can now be used in something like.

```
List<string> patientStrings = (from patient in database.PatientSet
        where patient.IsActive && patient.Account == r.Account
        select patient).ToString().ToList();
```

(I really don't know if that last syntax is correct as I never write Linq statements with the 'from' keyword, I use lambdas.)

If I'm translating properly it would be:

```
List<string> patientStrings = database.PatientSet
    .Where(patient => patient.IsActive && patient.Account == r.Account)
    .ToString()
    .ToList();
```